# How to pause JW Player on Ipad without controls

Tags: ipad, jwplayer, jwplayer7

**JW player**, if you hide the control bar you can click the video to play and pause, this works fine in desktop.

When I tested this in ipad it plays but touching it again doesn't pause the video.

Verify with this URL, https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406723-basic-video-embed

**Dont use the control bar as I need it disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hide the JW controls, then the player should also not react to clicking on the video as a means to start/stop unless you specifically add code to tell it to.

For this to happen you need to attach a function to the *onDisplayClick* event listener as follows:

```
**JW6 version**
jwplayer().onDisplayClick(function(){
    jwplayer().play();
});

**JW7 version**
jwplayer().on('displayClick',function(){
    jwplayer().play();
});
```

Just calling the *play()* method in this way will handle the toggle of play/pause states - you don't need to manage this yourself.

Comment: Hi, I was pretty sure that JW Team has some function inbuilt for this but I was not getting that. Your answer looks neater and proper, but I am not able to make it work on IOS, Ipad.

Have you tried it on any IOS?

Comment: Yes, iPad Mini 2 with iOS9.2 works fine.

Check this example here: [Example for sunnyuff](http://dev.powered-by-haiku.co.uk/debug/sunnyuff/).

Which versions of iOS & JW Player are you dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it in proper way but that doesn't seem to work alright, this is the only solution works for me,

```
$('.video-wrapper').on({ 'touchend' : 
                    function(){
                        if(dtjwplayer.getState() !== 'paused') {
                            dtjwplayer.pause(true); 
                        }
                    } 
                });
```

This is a very basic requirement where people wants to disable the control bar, Please let me know if there is any better way to do it.